# Stripe Android - AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter get footer layout events

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I'm integrating stripe's Add card screen.

Using stripe's AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter to launch the add card screen

Using below code:

```
// launch stripe's add card UI

 new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter(StripeAddCardActivity.this).startForResult(
                        new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Args.Builder()
                                .setAddPaymentMethodFooter(R.layout.stripe_footer_layout)
                                .build());


//initalize checkbox

CheckBox stripeSaveCardCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.stripeSaveCardCheckbox);

if(stripeSaveCardCheckbox !=null){
   if(stripeSaveCardCheckbox.isChecked()){
     Toast.makeText(this, "save card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else{
           Toast.makeText(this, "don't save card",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "CHECKBOX NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

I need to get the checkbox value of the footer layout(R.layout.stripe_footer_layout). but even after initializing it I always get null.

Could anyone help me get the footer XML value from stripe's add card screen?

**stripe_footer_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/stripeSaveCardCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_portmonie_selector"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:fontFamily="@fonts/helvetica_new"
        android:textSize="@dimen/community_avis_16px"
        android:text="@string/hint_card_checkbox_content"
        android:textColor="@color/community_black_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also share your layout for stripe_footer_layout and how you're trying to pull the checkbox value?

Comment: @karbi I've edited my code above

Comment: It looks like you're calling findViewById(R.id.stripeSaveCardCheckbox) before you even launch the AddPaymentMethodActivity. What happens if you initialize stripeSaveCardCheckbox afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I tried in that way too. But still it is coming as null